# How do I add an attribute to a Jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dialog function from jquery that works fine.  I also have a "Processing" function in my javascript that gets triggered when any submit/href link is posted.  The close button ("x" in the top right corner) triggers the submit/href function somehow. I would like to add an onclick attribute on the close button to call my "NoProcessing" (js function to prevent the href/submit processing.js file from being triggered) when it closes.  How do I add do that?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog(
      autoOpen: false,
      overflow: 'hidden',
      width: ($('#dialog').width() + 130)
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to prevent the default behaviour of the close button link, so that it doesn't update the url?

Comment: Question is not quite clear. You want to add a click event to the close button to prevent the href? Do you mean you want to stop the link from going to another page on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a close event

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog(
      autoOpen: false,
      overflow: 'hidden',
        close: function(event, ui) { 
            // do somehting
                            //maybe 
                          event.preventDefault();
                          notProcesseing();

        },
      width: ($('#dialog').width() + 130)
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: It seems like I'm making progress.  I just need to know how to call my notProcessing() function from my inherited js file. I made some edit changes

Answer (score 1):

It should be on 'beforeClose'.  Close is fired after the dialog is already closed.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    beforeClose: function(event, ui) { 
        event.preventDefault(true); 
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Then to remove the anchor or href tag, you could:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) { 
        $('span.ui-icon-closethick').removeAttr('href');
    }
});
```

Comment: That will prevent the dialog from closing !

Comment: Yes. I might have misunderstood the question. but that is what i though he was asking for.

Comment: I would like to close the dialog, but for some reason, my submit/href processing function is being hit

Comment: because the x close button in an href he want to prvent the trigger of href

Comment: @mcgrailim - That is correct!  I would like to call my notProcesseing() function in my inherited js file.  I made some edits